# Read JSON from file to dropdownlist in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, drop-down-menu

I'm having trouble reading JSON files for inclusion in the drop-down list.

JSON:

```
{
"BD": "Bangladesh",
"BE": "Belgium",
"BF": "Burkina Faso",
"BG": "Bulgaria",
"BA": "Bosnia and Herzegovina"
}
```

I want to put values into the dropdownlist as follows:
Example:

```
<select name="optCountry" id="opt_country">
   <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
   <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
   <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
   <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
   <option value="BH">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`JSON.parse()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjv-Obm94fUAhVI9WMKHWgxBigQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjs%2Fjs_json_parse.asp&usg=AFQjCNHVvxfmhUyq1X9aPG4nMXxbLeLLIg) use with convert the json string to Object and [`Object.keys()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiPsqzf94fUAhVBGmMKHS3yCVsQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FObject%2Fkeys&usg=AFQjCNHxNfTCTiOC4tCXBdJjQ2o4l76MOw) use with separate the key value to array .Then iterate the key value using [`Array#forEach`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiL7Pqs-IfUAhUL02MKHc3_B2EQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2FforEach&usg=AFQjCNFWWfwOQKjXdfPWyAU9FxufcTqwMg) .[`document.createElement`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjLzZrd-IfUAhVL52MKHXGYD9cQFggqMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FAPI%2FDocument%2FcreateElement&usg=AFQjCNFR_KTbv3XscmyERMuW_4JyLTamFQ) used for create the `select` element form the Dom

```js
var a = '{"BD": "Bangladesh","BE": "Belgium","BF": "Burkina Faso","BG":"Bulgaria","BA": "Bosnia and Herzegovina"}'
var obj = JSON.parse(a);
var select = document.createElement('SELECT')
select.name="optCountry" 
select.id="opt_country"
document.body.appendChild(select)

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(a){
document.getElementById('opt_country').innerHTML +='<option value="'+a+'">'+obj[a]+'</option>'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over your json by [Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) and make an option group.then append it to a select element using [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

```js
var json = '{"BD": "Bangladesh","BE": "Belgium","BF": "Burkina Faso","BG":"Bulgaria","BA": "Bosnia and Herzegovina"}';
var data = JSON.parse(json);
var result='';
for (var property in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
 result+='<option value="'+property+'">'+data[property]+'</option>';
    }
}
document.getElementById('opt_country').innerHTML=result;
```

```html
<select name="optCountry" id="opt_country">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?
It is considered that your JSON data is stored in the variable `js_data`:

```
const droplist = document.getElementById("opt_country")
droplist.innerHTML = "" //clear the dropdown list
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(js_data).forEach(function(element){
    droplist.innerHTML += '<option value="'+element+'">'+js_data[element]+'</option>'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
var Country= {
"BD": "Bangladesh",
"BE": "Belgium",
"BF": "Burkina Faso",
"BG": "Bulgaria",
"BA": "Bosnia and Herzegovina"
}
var strInnerHTML = "";
$.each(Country, function( index, value ) {
  strInnerHTML +='<option value="'+index+'">'+value+'</option>';
});
 document.getElementById('opt_country').innerHTML = strInnerHTML;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="optCountry" id="opt_country">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var obj = JSON.parse('{
    "BD": "Bangladesh",
    "BE": "Belgium",
    "BF": "Burkina Faso",
    "BG": "Bulgaria",
    "BA": "Bosnia and Herzegovina"
    }');

    //using jquery
    x=[]
    $.each(myObj, function(i,n) {
        x.push(n);});

     $.each(x, function (key, value) {
                         $("#opt_country").append($("<option></option>").val(key).html(value[key]));
                    });

//add following script to include jquery :
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```